# Snowflake "Pivot" for dynamic columns with dbt macro

Tags: jinja2, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, dbt

Starting context:

1. There is a dbt_utils "pivot" function. This question is *not* concerned with that function.
2. There is [some](https://community.snowflake.com/s/question/0D50Z00008TTgZASA1/what-is-the-best-way-to-dynamically-pivot-a-table) [discussion](https://medium.com/snowflake/dynamic-pivots-in-sql-with-snowflake-c763933987c) about the limitations of Snowflake's built-in [PIVOT](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/constructs/pivot.html), namely the inability to use dynamic columns and/or values for this function.

`example_model.sql`

```
with pivot as (
    select * 
    from {{ ref('my_base_model') }}
        pivot( sum(VALUE) for KEY in ( 
        {{ dbt_utils.get_column_values(table=ref('my_base_model'), column='KEY') }} 
        ) )
)

select * from pivot
```

dbt resolves that handily except for one hickup. When the above is compiled (code block below), it generates the values as a python list `[...]` when snowflake is expecting more like a tuple `(...)`

```
with pivot as (
    select * 
    from DB.SCHEMA.my_base_model
        pivot( sum(VALUE) for KEY in ( ['value_1', 'value_2', 'value_3', 'value_4', 'value_5', 'value_6', 'value_7'] ) )
)

select * from pivot
```

I was looking into using something like `as_native` to cast the resulting list to a tuple but have been unsuccessful so far.

Error within the `dbt run`:

```
001003 (42000): SQL compilation error:
  syntax error line 5 at position 39 unexpected '['.
  syntax error line 5 at position 961 unexpected ']'.
  compiled SQL at target\run\dbtproject\models\staging\my_application
\my_base_model.sql
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps not the *best* answer, but a working answer is:

`pivot_model.sql`

```
{% set pivot_cols = dbt_utils.get_column_values(table=ref('my_base_model'), column='KEY') %}

with pivot as (
    select * 
    from {{ ref('my_base_model') }}
        pivot( sum(VALUE) for KEY in (
            {% for pivot_col in pivot_cols %}
                '{{pivot_col}}'{% if not loop.last %}, {% endif%}
            {% endfor %}
         ))
)

select * from pivot
```

Answer (score 1):

** UPDATE 2 **:
As `tuple` is not supported as a filter in Jinja, so we can use `join` instead:

```
with pivot as (
    select * 
    from {{ ref('my_base_model') }}
        pivot( sum(VALUE) for KEY in ( 
        {{ dbt_utils.get_column_values(table=ref('my_base_model'), column='KEY') | join(",") }} 
        )
)

select * from pivot
```

** UPDATE 1 **:
In case you'd like to do it with `dbt`, let's try this:

1. Convert `dbt_utils.get_column_values`'s result to `tuple`

```
with pivot as (
    select * 
    from {{ ref('my_base_model') }}
        pivot( sum(VALUE) for KEY in ( 
        {{ dbt_utils.get_column_values(table=ref('my_base_model'), column='KEY') | tuple }} 
        ) )
)

select * from pivot
```

2. You can always try to create a custom dbt macro which is copy of `dbt_utils.get_column_values` in your local project and to use it:

Origin [get_column_values](https://github.com/dbt-labs/dbt-utils/blob/main/macros/sql/get_column_values.sql)

Custom:

```
...
{%- set values = value_list['data'] | map(attribute=0) | tuple %}
...
```

** ORIGIN **
Please see carefully the [pivot doc](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/constructs/pivot.html).

```
SELECT ...
FROM ...
   PIVOT ( <aggregate_function> ( <pivot_column> )
            FOR <value_column> IN ( <pivot_value_1> [ , <pivot_value_2> ... ] ) )

[ ... ]
```

It doesn't have [ ] which is incorect in your query

So the fix should be:

```
with pivot as (
    select * 
    from DB.SCHEMA.my_base_model
        pivot( sum(VALUE) for KEY in ( 'value_1', 'value_2', 'value_3', 'value_4', 'value_5', 'value_6', 'value_7' ) )
)

select * from pivot
```

Comment: Hi Dat, if this was a statically typed script using just SnowSQL - that answer would be perfect. However, I am attempting to replicate this functionality within [dbt](http://getdbt.com) which means that your answer would not apply to this requirement.

Comment: @sgoley oops sorry, my mistake that not to read the question carefully.So your answer will be perfect bro! Another way we can try to convert `dbt_utils.get_column_values`'s result to `tuple` type instead of `list` type

Comment: @sgoley Updated my answer. Thanks for your comment

Comment: Dat, just making a note that currently as of version 0.21 of dbt and 0.7.0 of dbt-utils, the `  | tuple ` modifier returns the following error:  `no filter named 'tuple'`

Comment: @sgoley: yeah you are correct! what about `({{ dbt.utils... | join(",")}})`?

Comment: Using the join solution, how do you quote each field? When I try it the fields aren't quoted so it doesn't work.