# Pivot table using crosstab and count

Tags: postgresql, pivot-table, dynamic-sql, crosstab, postgres-crosstab

I have to display a table like this:

| Year | Month | Delivered | Not delivered | Not Received |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2021 | Jan | 10 | 86 | 75 |
| 2021 | Feb | 13 | 36 | 96 |
| 2021 | March | 49 | 7 | 61 |
| 2021 | Apr | 3 | 21 | 72 |

Using raw data generated by this query:

```
SELECT 
    year,
    TO_CHAR( creation_date, 'Month') AS month,
    marking,
    COUNT(*) AS count 
FROM invoices
GROUP BY 1,2,3
```

I have tried using `crosstab()` but I got error:

```
SELECT * FROM crosstab('
    SELECT 
        year,
        TO_CHAR( creation_date, ''Month'') AS month,
        marking,
        COUNT(*) AS count 
    FROM invoices
    GROUP BY 1,2,3
') AS ct(year text, month text, marking text)
```

I would prefer to not manually type all marking values because they are a lot.

> ```
> ERROR:  invalid source data SQL statement
> DETAIL:  The provided SQL must return 3 columns: rowid, category, and values.
> ```

Comment: These two answers show that it gets very difficult to do N dynamic columns especially if you want N *named* dynamic columns... [A1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15514334/3073340) [A2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30502937/3073340) good luck! For my own cases, I've only learned how to do this by utilizing [dbt](https://www.getdbt.com/) which enables jinja templating - my tangentially related [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69979720/snowflake-pivot-for-dynamic-columns-with-dbt-macro) but with slightly different syntax (snowflake).

Comment: @sgoley. I agree with you that getting N named dynamic columns is a bit difficult issue with pg. I try to propose in my answer a full dynamic solution which is an alternative to the `crosstab` solutions you mention in your comment.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**1. Static solution with a limited list of `marking` values :**

```
SELECT year
     , TO_CHAR( creation_date, 'Month') AS month
     , COUNT(*) FILTER (WHERE marking = 'Delivered') AS Delivered
     , COUNT(*) FILTER (WHERE marking = 'Not delivered') AS "Not delivered"
     , COUNT(*) FILTER (WHERE marking = 'Not Received') AS "Not Received"
FROM invoices
GROUP BY 1,2
```

**2. Full dynamic solution with a large list of `marking` values :**

This proposal is an alternative solution to the `crosstab` solution as proposed in [A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15506199/dynamic-alternative-to-pivot-with-case-and-group-by/15514334#15514334) and [B](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12988575/crosstab-with-a-large-or-undefined-number-of-categories/12989297#12989297).

The proposed solution here just requires a dedicated `composite type` which can be dynamically created and then it relies on the `jsonb` type and standard functions :

Starting from your query which counts the number of rows per year, month and `marking` value :

- Using the `jsonb_object_agg` function, the resulting rows are first
  aggregated by year and month into `jsonb` objects whose `jsonb keys`
  correspond to the `marking` values and whose `jsonb values`
  correspond to the counts.
- the resulting `jsonb` objects are then converted into records using the `jsonb_populate_record` function and the dedicated composite type.

First we dynamically create a `composite type` which corresponds to the ordered list of `marking` values :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE create_composite_type() LANGUAGE plpgsql AS $$
DECLARE
  column_list text ;
BEGIN
  SELECT string_agg(DISTINCT quote_ident(marking) || ' bigint', ',' ORDER BY quote_ident(marking) || ' bigint' ASC)
    INTO column_list
    FROM invoices ;
  
  EXECUTE 'DROP TYPE IF EXISTS composite_type' ;
  EXECUTE 'CREATE TYPE composite_type AS (' || column_list || ')' ;
END ;
$$ ;

CALL create_composite_type() ;
```

Then the expected result is provided by the following query :

```
SELECT a.year
     , TO_CHAR(a.year_month, 'Month') AS month
     , (jsonb_populate_record( null :: composite_type
                             , jsonb_object_agg(a.marking, a.count)
                             )
       ).*
 FROM
    ( SELECT year
           , date_trunc('month', creation_date) AS year_month
           , marking
           , count(*) AS count
        FROM invoices AS v
       GROUP BY 1,2,3
    ) AS a
GROUP BY 1,2
ORDER BY month
```

Obviously, if the list of `marking` values may vary in time, then you have to recall the `create_composite_type()` procedure just before executing the query. If you don't update the `composite_type`, the query will still work (no error !) but some old marking values may be obsolete (not used anymore), and some new marking values may be missing in the query result (not displayed as columns).

See the full demo in [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=dd7ccc40bcaf77009a481e5ab7ac9aca).

Comment: I have to use cross tab because the marking values are a lot and I prefer something dynamic as a pivot table.

Comment: This proposed solution is fully dynamic, it can manage a large number of marking values which can vary in time, and it avoids to use a pivot table, so I don't really see what's wrong with it.

Comment: @Edouard, I came up with several related JSON methods, thinking of turning it into a full Q&A. The record-set composite type is the key to the kingdom, esp. as the JSON functions are very forgiving about mismatches.

Answer (score 2):

You need to generate the `crosstab()` call dynamically.
But since SQL does not allow dynamic return types, you need a two-step workflow:

1. Generate query
2. Execute query

If you are unfamiliar with `crosstab()`, read this first:

- [PostgreSQL Crosstab Query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3002499/postgresql-crosstab-query/11751905#11751905)

It's odd to generate the month from `creation_date`, but not the year. To simplify, I use a combined column `year_month` instead.

Query to generate the `crosstab()` query:

```sql
SELECT format(
$f$SELECT * FROM crosstab(
   $q$
   SELECT to_char(date_trunc('month', creation_date), 'YYYY_Month') AS year_month
        , marking
        , COUNT(*) AS ct
   FROM   invoices
   GROUP  BY date_trunc('month', creation_date), marking
   ORDER  BY date_trunc('month', creation_date)  -- optional
   $q$
 , $c$VALUES (%s)$c$
   ) AS ct(year_month text, %s);
$f$, string_agg(quote_literal(sub.marking), '), (')
   , string_agg(quote_ident  (sub.marking), ' int, ') || ' int'
)
FROM  (SELECT DISTINCT marking FROM invoices ORDER BY 1) sub;
```

If the table `invoices` is *big* with only *few* distinct values for marking (which seems likely) there are faster ways to get distinct values. See:

- [Optimize GROUP BY query to retrieve latest row per user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25536422/optimize-group-by-query-to-retrieve-latest-row-per-user/25536748#25536748)

Generates a query of the form:

```sql
SELECT * FROM crosstab(
   $q$
   SELECT to_char(date_trunc('month', creation_date), 'YYYY_Month') AS year_month
        , marking
        , COUNT(*) AS ct
   FROM   invoices
   GROUP  BY date_trunc('month', creation_date), marking
   ORDER  BY date_trunc('month', creation_date)  -- optional
   $q$
 , $c$VALUES ('Delivered'), ('Not Delivered'), ('Not Received')$c$
   ) AS ct(year_month text, "Delivered" int, "Not Delivered" int, "Not Received" int);
```

The simplified query does not need "extra columns. See:

- [Pivot on Multiple Columns using Tablefunc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15415446/pivot-on-multiple-columns-using-tablefunc/15421607#15421607)

Note the use `date_trunc('month', creation_date)` in `GROUP BY` and `ORDER BY`. This produces a valid sort order, and faster, too. See:

- [Cumulative sum of values by month, filling in for missing months](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32490946/cumulative-sum-of-values-by-month-filling-in-for-missing-months/32491058#32491058)
- [How to get rows by max(date) group by Year-Month in Postgres?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67745700/how-to-get-rows-by-maxdate-group-by-year-month-in-postgres/67745871#67745871)

Also note the use of dollar-quotes to avoid quoting hell. See:

- [Insert text with single quotes in PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12316953/insert-text-with-single-quotes-in-postgresql/12320729#12320729)

Months without entries don't show up in the result, and no markings for an existing month show as `NULL`. You can adapt either if need be. See:

- [Join a count query on generate_series() and retrieve Null values as '0'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13413715/join-a-count-query-on-generate-series-and-retrieve-null-values-as-0/13414797#13414797)

Then execute the generated query.

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=87eb25c4a2b87ded23fb0848979b7ab3)* (reusing
Edouard's fiddle, kudos!)

See:

- [Execute a dynamic crosstab query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36804551/execute-a-dynamic-crosstab-query/36831103#36831103)

#### In psql

In [psql](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-psql.html) you can use `\qexec` to immediately execute the generated query. See:

- [Simulate CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS for PostgreSQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18389124/simulate-create-database-if-not-exists-for-postgresql/18389184#18389184)

In Postgres 9.6 or later, you can also use the meta-command `\crosstabview` ***instead*** of `crosstab()`:

```sql
test=> SELECT to_char(date_trunc('month', creation_date), 'YYYY_Month') AS year_month
test->      , marking
test->      , COUNT(*) AS count
test-> FROM   invoices
test-> GROUP  BY date_trunc('month', creation_date), 2
test-> ORDER  BY date_trunc('month', creation_date)\crosstabview

   year_month   | Not Received | Delivered | Not Delivered 
----------------+--------------+-----------+---------------
 2020_January   |            1 |         1 |             1
 2020_March     |              |         2 |             2
 2021_January   |            1 |         1 |             2
 2021_February  |            1 |           |              
 2021_March     |              |         1 |              
 2021_August    |            2 |         1 |             1
 2022_August    |              |         2 |              
 2022_November  |            1 |         2 |             3
 2022_December  |            2 |           |              
(9 rows)
```

Note that `\crosstabview` - unlike `crosstab()` - does not support "extra" columns. If you insist on separate year and month columns, you need `crosstab()`.

See:

- [How do I generate a pivoted CROSS JOIN where the resulting table definition is unknown?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/159286/3684)