# Create a pivot table in PostgreSQL with a long list of dynamic columns without hard-coding the columns in SQL

Tags: postgresql, dynamic, pivot-table

I have a hits table in PostgreSQL that contains a record for each product found in a certain shop.

It looks like this (simplified):

| id | shop | product |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | shop1 | product1 |
| 2 | shop1 | product85 |
| 3 | shop3 | product1 |
| 4 | shop3 | product1 |
| 5 | shop4 | product23 |
| 6 | shop4 | product64 |
| 7 | shop4 | product128 |

As you can see for shop 3, a certain shop may have more than one hit for a certain product.

I want to query it in a way that I get as the output of the query this simple pivot table (which I will use to create a view), where 1 means, the respective shop has the specific product in stock, and 0 means, it doesn't:

| id | shop | product1 | product2 | ... | product23 | ... | product64 | ... | product85 ... |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | shop1 | 1 | 0 | ... | 0 | ... | 0 | ... | 1 |
| 2 | shop3 | 1 | 0 | ... | 0 | ... | 0 | ... | 0 |
| 3 | shop4 | 0 | 0 | ... | 1 | ... | 1 | ... | 0 |

**Please note:** I do not want to hard-code all the columns, as there are many and the number of products might change.

I would prefer not to use `crosstab` from the tablefunc extension.

Comment: Not possible. A fundamental restriction of the SQL language is, that the number, names and data types of all columns of a query must be know to the engine _before_ the query is being executed (i.e. when parsing the query). There are two workarounds: create a view dynamically when the number of products changes (and then wait until it fails if you have more than ~1500 products). Or aggregate into a JSON structure, e.g. like [this](https://blog.sql-workbench.eu/post/pivot-alternatives). A pivot table like that is better done in the GUI of your application.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Thanks. I'm trying to figure out if [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70466824/1687087) from another thread offers a solution.

Comment: The "workaround" with a type seems rather pointless if you can create a view dynamically as well. But in any case you'll hit the limit on the number of roughly 1500 columns in a view or query quickly with any real world online shop.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Currently, the number of products is in the low hundreds. I do not expect to exceed 1000 anytime soon, if at all. I could also build different views for different ranges of products.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I guess you are right. In the end, we only wanted to use the pivot table as a basis for more specific visualisations in QuickSight, which we now realised we can also achieve in a different way. In most other cases, a JSON structure would probably be most appropriate.