# Create columns from distinct values of a column

Tags: sql, postgresql, pivot-table, dynamic-sql, postgres-crosstab

I have a large dataset with many different product. In a small scale it would look like this:

| product | month | amount |
| --- | --- | --- |
| AA | 1 | 100 |
| AA | 1 | 150 |
| AA | 2 | 200 |
| AA | 2 | 120 |
| BB | 2 | 180 |
| BB | 2 | 220 |
| CC | 3 | 80 |

I want get the info in a different order. Write as many new columns as distinct values from the column "product", then fill it with the sum of the amount by month. It would look like this:

| month | AA | BB | CC |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 250 | NA | NA |
| 2 | 320 | 400 | NA |
| 3 | NA | NA | 80 |

The important thing is to PIVOT the table, that's the main problem I have. I saw similar questions but all have being solved with PIVOT function but I'm doing this with a Postgres database in DBeaver and it doesn't have the PIVOT function:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT product, month, amount
    FROM ventas
) AS SourceTable
PIVOT (
    SUM(amount)
    FOR month IN ([1], [2], [3])
) AS PivotTable;
```

> SQL Error [42601]: ERROR: syntax error at or near "PIVOT"
> Position: 95

I've tried different ways but no success. **I can't write the names of all products in the query as there are too many!**

Here is a test setup for your convenience:

```
CREATE TABLE ventas (
    product VARCHAR(50),
    month INT,
    amount INT
);

INSERT INTO ventas (product, month, amount) VALUES 
('AA', 1, 100),
('AA', 1, 150),
('AA', 2, 200),
('AA', 2, 120),
('BB', 2, 180),
('BB', 2, 220),
('CC', 3, 80),
```

Comment: postgres has no command PIVOT use CROSSTAB instead see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20618323/create-a-pivot-table-with-postgresql

Comment: Thanks nbk. It's a good info, but in this case, how can I solve the fact that there are many unique values for the column and I can't type all of them? Because in this example and all that I checked they are written, and I have to create more than 100 columns

Comment: For unknown number of columns you almost always have to use dynamic sql. That being said, why can't you have result having 12 months as columns x n products as rows?

Comment: Do you actually **need** 100 separate output columns? Else, an array (for same data types) or a document type like json / jsonb / hstore / xml is much easier to handle ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you actually need separate output columns, the only reasonable approach is a 2-step flow:

1. Generate the query dynamically.
2. Execute it.

If you are not familiar with the `crosstab()` function, read this first:

- [PostgreSQL Crosstab Query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3002499/postgresql-crosstab-query/11751905#11751905)

```sql
-- generate crosstab() query
SELECT format(
$f$  -- begin dynamic query string
SELECT * FROM crosstab(
   $q$
   SELECT month, product, sum(amount)
   FROM   ventas
   GROUP  BY 1, 2
   ORDER  BY 1, 2
   $q$
 , $c$VALUES (%s)$c$
   ) AS ct(month int, %s);
$f$  -- end dynamic query string
            , string_agg(quote_literal(sub.product), '), (')
            , string_agg(quote_ident  (sub.product), ' int, ') || ' int'
                 )
FROM  (SELECT DISTINCT product FROM ventas ORDER BY 1) sub;
```

This generates a query of the form:

```sql
SELECT * FROM crosstab(
   $q$
   SELECT month, product, sum(amount)
   FROM   ventas
   GROUP  BY 1, 2
   ORDER  BY 1, 2
   $q$
 , $c$VALUES ('AA'), ('BB'), ('CC')$c$
   ) AS ct(month int, "AA" int, "BB" int, "CC" int);
```

... which you then execute.

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/y8mj1GZ0)

Closely related, with more explanation and options:

- [Pivot table using crosstab and count](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70460909/pivot-table-using-crosstab-and-count/70561870#70561870)

Comment: Thank you so much Erwin! Appreciate the fiddle tool, got it!

Comment: But from what I understand, you always have to type the name of the columns of the product, and in my real case there are more than 100... any idea?

Comment: @FranciscoMS: No you don't type any product names here. Postgres does that for you, that's the point.

Comment: Thank you Erwin, understood all, thanks so much!!!